# Is it possible for an ETF to go bankrupt?

Tags: etf, bankruptcy

ETFs have liabilities and expenses. What if the value of the ETF's holdings fall to such a point where the assets do not cover the liabilities and expenses? Is it possible for ETFs to go bankrupt in such situations? If so, could you give a concrete example where this has happened?

Comment: ETFs have been worth zero before. But I assume the question is not whether its value can go to zero as an expected part of how that ETF operates, but whether it could e.g. run out of liquidity despite the underlying value not being zero

Answer (score 1):

Before an ETF can go bankrupt, the fund's managers will liquidate it, if they feel that it is their fiduciary duty to do so, or if doing so doesn't violate their duty and is profitable for their management company.

Realistically, this is only a worry for leveraged ETFs and ETNs.

During the COVID crash, [UBS](https://www.investorsalley.com/ubs-launches-4-leveraged-etfs-after-12-collapse-in-april-article-tim/) liquidated 12 of its leveraged ETNs.

Comment: An ETN is a quite different instrument to an ETF.... ETNs are actually structured as a debt instrument and if the issuer fails, so does the ETN (you would become a creditor of the issuer irrespective of the assets held by the ETN).  An ETF actually holds assets which would be liquidated/redeemed even if the issuer fails.

Comment: Thanks, added reference to leverage.

Comment: The Lehman Brothers-issued ETNs provide you with a 0% return when Lehman Brothers went bankrupt in 2008   They weren't leveraged.  If you held the ETN, you became a creditor.

Comment: You mean they provided a -100% return? I.e. lost all your money?